# Should I ask a duplicate question if the existing answer does not solve the issue?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Occasionally I have find soemone has posted exactly the question I want an answer to, but the accepted answer doesn't solve the problem for me. Should I post a duplicate question anyway?

For example, imagine this hypothetical scenario:

> **Question:**
>
> What is 3+3?
>
> **Answer (marked correct):**
>
> Use multiplication instead: 3*3 = 9

The answer apparently solves whatever problem the original poster was having, so they marked it correct, but not the question they actually asked. I still need an answer the the actual, asked question, but as it already has an accepted answer, is not likely to attract new answers. Should I just post a duplicate? Or just hope that someone will come along and post a new answer on it anyway?

Comment: @rene slightly different question, in that they are asking what to do if the question you are duplicating doesn't have an accepted answer - I'm asking what to do if it does.

Comment: @Benubird It covers both cases.

Comment: Ahh, the irony!

Comment: I feel his pain--every day it seems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When future visitors come to a question, the first thing they're going to do is to match the OP's problem to their own.

If the answer solved the OP's problem did not solve your problem then obviously you and the OP obviously have different problems, and since your problems are different, your questions won't actually be duplicates.

To differentiate your question from the OP's question, describe the specific requirements that are preventing you from making use of the answer that solved the OP's problem.

Once you do that, your question and the original question will no longer be duplicates.

Comment: Sometimes the question the OP asks, is not the problem they need solving. e.g. if they ask about how to implement PGP, the accepted answer might be a link to an existing library, which works for them because that was what they actually needed, they just weren't aware it existed. But that won't help someone who can't use that library.

Comment: @Benubird therefore the new question you ask won't be an actual duplicate

Comment: Example question: "Wine is throwing exception_X when I try to run Program_Y on linux, what does it mean?" Answer: "[here] is a link to a port of Program_Y for windows, use that instead". Which solves the problem he was having, but doesn't actually answer the question. future visitors might actually need to know what Exception_X means, rather than just be trying to run Program_Y.