# I want to re-ask a question whose accepted answer is "don't do that"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In particular, I was wondering how to write directly to video memory using C. Turns out, almost exactly this question was asked previously:

[Can I write bytes directly to video memory under Linux, or is there a better way to get data onto the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694148/easiest-way-to-get-direct-access-to-video-memory)

However, the accepted answer doesn't answer the question, but instead gives the ever-popular "You don't really want to do this". This might have been true for the original asker, but I actually *do* really want do this. What's the suggested way of dealing with this? Can I just ask the same question again?

Comment: open a new question, shoot a link to the other question you found, explain why the answers there do not apply to you (and give more than just "it doesn't help me"), so people don't duplicate-close

Comment: Well, there is no other reason. I have the same question and it wasn't answered there.

Comment: Explain the why, give more context than just "it doesn't help me". Explain WHY you REALLY need to do this, so why SDL doesn't help you out

Comment: cross site duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: One of the reasons we have bounties is to cover exactly this need: encourage people to post better answers to questions that do not have satisfactory answers.

Comment: Can you add bounties for questions that already have an accepted answer?

Comment: @Benno Yes, you can.

Comment: @Patrice sometimes you really do need to do things.  How would you use SDL on an embedded system with 256 bytes of RAM?  I don't agree that a valid answer is "don't do that" because if they wanted other ways of doing it the question would be "is writing directly to memory the best way?  And if so, how do I do it?"

Comment: @JerryJeremiah so, including "I can't do this because I'm on an embedded with only 256 bytes of RAM" isn't a justification now? THAT'S what I was asking for :P

Comment: @Patrice good point

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I ask a duplicate question if the existing answer does not solve the issue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265258/should-i-ask-a-duplicate-question-if-the-existing-answer-does-not-solve-the-issu) - *no, wait*. This new question was originally answered with "don't do that" - but you really really really want to.

Comment: Realistically, the answer is closer to "you can't really do this" than "you don't want to do this". I'd rather go down the path of virtualization myself. If you must work directly with pixels, that is exactly what you can achieve with image buffers today in any language, operating system and technology. don't write to memory and have it appear on screen - write to an image buffer and paint that to the screen. Let the OS take care of the (virtual) memory mapping.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah The answer is going to depend on your embedded system. The question you linked was implicitly about PCs, so your question will not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a slightly tricky one. A decent question, with a decent answer, which superficially is exactly what you want to ask and exactly what you don't want as an answer.

But notice that the body of the question doesn't quite align with the title: it allows for the possibility of another solution. And that the title *certainly* doesn't match the accepted solution.

[A quick title edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17694148/2) to [match the accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272663/how-to-deal-with-questions-whose-title-description-and-accepted-answer-dont-m?lq=1) ([cf.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283130/is-it-ok-to-edit-someone-elses-question-or-answer-when-the-choice-of-accepted-a)) means that this is much more clearly *not* a valid search result for your problem. That should make it straightforward for you to mention this in your own question. Something along the lines of "Question X asks about this, but resolved the problem with a workaround. I really truly want to write directly to video memory" should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

"You don't really want to do this" is the sort of answer you might give to an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's not uncommon to latch on to 'I just need to ...' when the actual answer is to do something else entirely.

One I see quite often is ['how to I parse XML with a regular expression'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and the answer is "You don't really want to do this" - despite being technically possible in a reasonable subset of cases (And likely quite workable given a very limited input-scope), it's the wrong solution to the problem.

... except, sometimes you really are stuck with a hammer when you need a screwdriver. (Off the top of my head: Embedded systems, systems with absurd change control constraints, legacy environments). In that scenario - "just don't" isn't an option. We all know there's a big difference between the theory of 'good practice' and the practicality of the real world. So you're left trying to smack screws into the wall. Recognising entirely that it's the wrong approach to take, but being told to JFDI anyway.

In that scenario - you may need to exclude certain options because of additional constraints imposed. That's fine. Refer back to the other answers (show you're doing your research). Explain those constraints.

There may still be a 'better' solution to your problem than what you're trying to do. There may not. But either way, you will attract answers that suit *your* scenario, as well as being useful to future readers - who'll read it and see both - your answer with the constraint, and the 'better' answer without.

Comment: Not a fan of this answer because it imposes an additional burden of proof: The asker not only has to ask a good question, but also has to prove that all other approaches won't be applicable to his specific situation. Quite often, it's necessary to see how the "incorrect" approach actually would look like to make an informed decision whether its viable or not. Also, sometimes there are no additional constraints but just curiosity.

Comment: No, not _all other_ approaches. Just explain what's different that the dupe isn't appropriate. "Just curiosity" is an acceptable reason why the dupe isn't appropriate, but still potentially ends up in an "XY Problem" scenario - when what you're doing is risky/brittle and unnecessary.