# How can I bring an attention to already answered question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I encountered the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759212/how-to-stop-infinite-loop-in-jshell-kulla). Except, the given answer didn't help to solve the problem. How can I encourage someone to help answer with another solution? I thought of re-asking the question, but then of course it's a duplicate. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: You can place a bounty on it, or ask your own pointing out that the answer in the other question doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Will but your link is about unanswered questions!  (Now that that's taken care of, can we close? :D )

Comment: See also: [Should I ask a duplicate question if the existing answer does not solve the issue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265258)